# How to make my 74LS90N BCD counter to start from 0?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, counter

I need this BCD counter to start at 0000. I have the circuit below, but for some reason it starts at 1000 (the `QA` output starts at 1). I have tried adding a reset push button on R0/1 and R0/2, but they don't work. Is there a way around this?

[image: schematic]

Comment: When you say 1000 might you have meant 0001?

Comment: Is CKB intentionally wired to QA? Why did you do this?

Comment: @Andyaka no, it really starts at 1000, i want it to start at 0000

Comment: @HansmitmFlammenwerfer i dont have a second clock, input, i only want it to count from 0-9, A always go 0 and 1

Comment: You have connect R0/1,2andR9/1,2 to gnd

Comment: @toolic QA starts at 1 for some reason

Comment: @Varun thats what i did

Comment: @Saylent please disconnect QA from CKB, maybe you don't see the output of QA but rather the leakage current of CKB.

Comment: Make R0/1 and R0/2 high and either of R9/0,1as low , to reset the counter and than observe.it should start from 0 as per data sheet

Comment: @HansmitmFlammenwerfer The '90 has a separate clock for stage A (CKA -> QA) and therefore it is the common way to wire a 4-bit decimal counter. (BTW, what a brutal nickname! You might want to reconsider it in these times.)

Comment: Why are all the resistors labelled "resistortoday"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by using a tri state rocker switch where the off state connects the vcc to the reset pins of the bcd counter, at the opposite end, whenever the tri state switch is on, it connects the vcc to the LM7805 voltage regulator's input pin, not really a decent solution but it works

Answer (score 1):

Bringing both R0 pins high at once will reset all 4 flip-flops.

If you want 400mV of noise immunity, there is no more than 0.8mA of Iil so you'd need a pull-down resistor of (800mV-400mV)/0.8mA = 500Ω. So maybe use 470Ω. It may be half that, allowing a 1kΩ pulldown depending on the exact input circuit.

This assumes a 74LS90, where it is acceptable to connect an input directly to Vcc and Iil is 0.4mA (max).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEMPeo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>